# Can not use telnet localhost 5554 to connect Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, port, firewall, telnet

I can't use the command `telnet localhost 5554` to connect Android emulator.
Always get this error:

> Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port
>   5554: Connect failed

I even have all ports set to allow connections in both the inbound and outbound rules in Windows Firewall.

I am running Windows 7.

Comment: Try disabling the firewall completely. I once had a similar issue and allowing ports inbound/outbound and even disabling the firewall didn't help, only uninstalling the firewall solved the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499803/has-anyone-been-successful-in-using-64-bit-eclipse-for-android-2-3-dev-on-64-bit/4881366#4881366

Comment: @Android Eve : Disabling the firewall doesn't help either.

Comment: Sorry all I need to launch the emulator before use telnet. My bad. Problem solved !

Comment: Told ya'! :-) Too bad comments need to be 15 characters...

Answer (score 6):

I've encountered this issue a few times, I'm not sure how the the emulator deals with addresses, but localhost just doesn't work for me.

Changing the connection command to `telnet 127.0.0.1 5554` enabled me to connect, so if localhost doesn't work, try 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Try using the complete command inside telnet:

```
Microsoft Telnet> open localhost 5554
```

That should work, sometimes we forget to write the entire command

Comment: Thank you for this. My issue was `telent: could not resolve localhost:5554/telnet: Name or service not known`.

I had been trying `telnet localhost:5554` in ubuntu. My problem was my inclusion of the colon. Using `telnet localhost 5554` - with a space instead of a colon - worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the netstat tool to verify the application is listening on that port. I'm not familiar with netstat on windows, but it seems you'll need -a -n and optionally the -o options.

If you see the process listening, keep looking at the firewall. If you don't see one, figure out why it's not running.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly ... you should enable Telnet command in windows .

check this
http://www.labnol.org/software/windows-telnet-command/18222/

then it will work :)

Answer (score 1):

first simply type telnet to your command prompt

Microsoft Telnet> open 127.0.0.1 5554

above line might show you following result

Android Console: Authentication required

Android Console: type 'auth ' to authenticate

Android Console: you can find your  in C:\Users\YOURPCNAME.emulator_console_auth_token'
OK

then go into your 'c' drive then user where you find .emulator_console_auth_token
open that file and put you auth token like below

auth ################

then you find

Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands

OK

it means you are connected now..

Answer (score 1):

If "telnet localhost 5554" doesnt work, try using port 5037.
Also ensure that the Emulator is running.

Answer (score 0):

In cmd: you press cd D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools. It is path to platform-tools in your computer. After you can input telnet localhost 5554

redir add udp:9876:9876 or redir add tcp:5000:6000