# Hello World will not load onto an Android Virtual Device at all. Why?

Tags: java, android, adt, android-virtual-device

I am using Eclipse 3.7.2
I have the standard Hello World application from the Android tutorial. When I try to run it on an AVD, Eclipse starts an AVD but never attempts to load the application onto it. The log reads:

```
[2012-05-06 11:23:01 - MyFirstAndroid] Android Launch!
[2012-05-06 11:23:01 - MyFirstAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2012-05-06 11:23:01 - MyFirstAndroid] Performing com.pack.myapp.MyFirstAndroidActivity activity launch
[2012-05-06 11:23:01 - MyFirstAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Device'
[2012-05-06 11:23:01 - MyFirstAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Device'
```

And that's it. The emulator launches, boots up, but my application is never loaded onto it.

Furthermore, I went into the Configurations for the application and tried changing the "Automatic Target Mode" to Manual mode, where I select which AVD to boot the app onto. It gives me the option of selecting a new AVD or an already running one, but when I have an AVD running, it does not show up on the list of "Running Android Devices." I am not sure why it does not recognize this.

Help me out please?

Setup:

Eclipse version 3.7.2

Windows Vista 32 bit

Android SDK Platform 4.0.3 API 15

SDK installer: installer_r18-windows.exe

Eclipse Android Development Toolkit plugin: 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4461575/977676

Comment: 32-bit, 64-bit, eclipse version? Can you give more details?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to restart your adb server if you can't find the emulator in the list of 'Running Android Devices' in DDMS you can go to the drop list next to the camera icon and 'Reset adb' or do it manually from the the command line.