# Not able to fetch data from Sqlite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlexception

I want to fetch data from SQLITE database and display it in a LIST.

My database name is AppDB.db and table name is Scrip which contains 3 columns _id(primary key) and symbol&company_name which are text.

I want to fetch only 2nd and 3rd column.   I have copied database in Assets folder.

I get force close when I execute following code but I don't know what might be the reason. Please help..

**I'm absolute beginner to Android, so any help appreciated...**

Contents:

1.) DataAttach.java

2.) DbManager.java

3.) LogCat

4.) .xml in brief

5.) AVD Problem

6.)  Snapshot of database

---

**1.) DataAttach.java**

```
public class DataAttach extends Activity {
    private DbManager dbM;
    private Cursor c;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            dbM = new DbManager(this);
            dbM.createDataBase();
            dbM.openDB();

            try {
                c = dbM.fetchAllData();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new Error("\n\nERROR Fetchin data\n\n");
            }

            if (c != null) {
                SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        c,
                        new String[] { c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id")),
                                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("symbol")),
                                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("company_name")) },
                        new int[] { R.id._id, R.id.symbol, R.id.company_name });
                ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MainLayout);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Error("\n\nERROR DB failure\n\n");
        }

        finally {
            c.close();
            dbM.close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**2.) DbManager.java**

```
public class DbManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_SYMBOL = "symbol";
    private static final String KEY_COMPANY_NAME = "company_name";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AppDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.dbexample/databases/";
    private static final Integer DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Scrip";
    // private static final String TAG = "DbManager";
    private final Context ctx;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    public DbManager(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.ctx = context;
    }

    /*
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
     * database.
     */
    public void createDataBase() {

        if (checkDataBase()) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {
            /*
             * By calling this method and empty database will be created into
             * the default system path of your application so we can overwrite
             * that database with our database.
             */
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("\n\nERROR copying database\n\n");
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            throw new Error("\n\nERROR database does't exist yet\n\n");
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /*
     * Copies your DB from your local assets-folder to the just created empty DB
     * in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        /* Open your local db as the input stream */
        InputStream myInput = ctx.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        /* Path to the just created empty db */
        String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        /* Open the empty db as the output stream */
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        /* transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile */
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDB() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        mDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        mDb.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllData() {
        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_SYMBOL,
                KEY_COMPANY_NAME }, null, null, null, null, null);

        // return mDb.rawQuery("select _id,symbol,company_name from Scrip",
        // new String[] { KEY_ROWID,KEY_SYMBOL, KEY_COMPANY_NAME });
    }
}
```

---

**3.) LOG CAT**

```
sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.dbexample/databases/AppDB", &handle, 1, NULL) failed

Failed to open the database. closing it.
    
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file
    
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
    
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1017)
```

---

4.) **Main.xml**

It contains RelativeLayout having 3 TextViews within RelativeLayout.

---

**5.) *I ALWAYS GET THIS ERROR***

Even after reopening the eclipse, restarting the system, recreating the AVD, trying, kill_server and start_server, I get this message.

```
Failed to install DataAttach.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device not found
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device not found
Launch canceled!
```

---

**6.) SCREENSHOT of DB :**

[image: Screenshot]

***WHOLE DOC EDITED TO LATEST CODE AND ACC. TO YOUR SUGGESTIONS, but still app doesn't work.***

Comment: SimpleCursorAdapter always need _id.so try fetching _id too in your cursor.

Comment: @Hiral - tried, but same prob :(

Comment: But then problem might something else too including this one..bcz you will always need _id to be passes to SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: agreed.
Tried closing unclosed cursor. but that too didn't worked.
btw, Thnx !!

Comment: WHOLE DOC EDITED TO LATEST CODE AND ACC. TO YOUR SUGGESTIONS, but still app doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do with this function. You're trying to read a .db file and say the DB is created. First time when you try to run there won't be a .db file in the database path. That is why the 'No such File or Directory' error is thrown.

```
11-25 12:06:13.398: E/Netd(31): Unable to bind netlink socket: No such file or directory
```

In the DBManager Constructor call the SQLiteOpenHelper's getReadableDatabase() which will create a db if there is not one. [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase%28%29)

```
 public void createNewDatabase() {
                InputStream assetsDB = null;
                try {
                    assetsDB = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
                    OutputStream dbOut = new FileOutputStream(DATABASE_PATH
                            + DATABASE_NAME);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = assetsDB.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        dbOut.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }

                    dbOut.flush();
                    dbOut.close();
                    assetsDB.close();
                    Log.i(TAG, "New database created...");
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not create new database...");
                }
            }
```

Comment: ya. Try calling getReadableDatabase() method in the constructor. Hoping it will work

Comment: ya have it in the constructor. anyway ur open method is non static method. So for sure u will create an object to call it. Having the statement in the constructor will be good

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the previous comment itself. U dont need the open method at all. Just have the getReadableDatabase() in the constructor which will create a db if it s not thre. open it if already there. Use that instance to do all ur db related functions

Comment: Hope u have tried adb -devices command in command prompt? Is it able to find the emulator-5554. If it is able to find, try installing the apk manually through command prompt.

Comment: got it.It's      adb install DataAttach.apk

but as soon as I get device not found exception, my device list(by using adb devices command) becomes empty and it fails to install the apk

Comment: Interesting but only thing which I can think of is to kill the process adb.exe in Task Manager and then try it.. If it doesn't work then some expert should help us.

Comment: Did u try killing the abd process?

Comment: Close all ur emulators and command prompt where u gave adb commands. After doing this if u find any adb.exe process running terminate it. Dont run the app and do it. It will then give forceful termination

Comment: done exactly the same i.e. Closed all emulators and command prompt where i give adb commands. After doing this i found an adb.exe process running, so i terminated it. wat next?

Comment: after i do above steps, it shows 

[2011-11-29 15:28:51 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2011-11-29 15:28:52 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 1 till 11.
and then i check task manager, there is adb.exe again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411295/error-adb-connection-erroran-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-r

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793956/android-emulator-wont-run-application-started-from-eclipse

Look at these links

Comment: can u mail me at surrams@gmail.com. We will chat it out

Comment: The **foolish** mistake I done is to create **`/data/data/com.dbexample/databases/`** directory manually and placing my DB in it. Actually I was supposed to copy my database straight into assets folder.

Answer (score 2):

`SimpleCursorAdapter` needs `_id` field in the `Cursor` you pass to it. So try to change your query like this:

```
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_SYMBOL, KEY_COMPANY_NAME }, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Also you are getting:

> android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application
>   did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here

Make sure you call `close()` on all `Cursor` objects you use when you are done with them.

Comment: after closing the cursor and passing ID, it still gives the same prob.
Thanks anyways !

Comment: WHOLE DOC EDITED TO LATEST CODE AND ACC. TO YOUR SUGGESTIONS, but still app doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think,you need to set the layout file as:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter sca=new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c, from, to);
```

Because you are passing R.layout.main which is giving you error in reloading same layout file.

I am not sure,but this might be the problem.
Also add _id in your cursor passed to adapter.

Comment: WHOLE DOC EDITED TO LATEST CODE AND ACC. TO YOUR SUGGESTIONS, but still app doesn't work.

Comment: @GAMA: sorry...i have no idea then! :(