# how to fetch data from sqlite database for login

Tags: android

I am a begginer in android please anyone help me how to fetch data from SQLite database for login, this is my MainActivity code.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    EditText nameText,phoneText;
    Button registeredButton,newUser;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        newUser =(Button)findViewById(R.id.new_user);
        newUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                nameText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_text);
                phoneText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass_text);
                String name=nameText.getText().toString();
                String phone=phoneText.getText().toString();
                AdapterClass ad1=new AdapterClass(getApplicationContext(),DatabaseDetail.REGISTER);
                ad1.Open();
                Cursor cursor=ad1.query("SELECT * FROM CUS_REGISTER WHERE CUS_NAME=? AND CUS_PHONE=?",new String[] { name, phone });
                 Cursor cursor = ad1.fetchRecords(new String[]{name,phone}, null);      
                startManagingCursor(cursor);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sucess", 5000).show();
                }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid", 5000).show();
                    }
            }
        });

    }
    }
```

This is athe code od Database Detail :

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
public class DatabaseDetail
{
    public static String REGISTER="CUS_REGISTER";
    public static String[] REG_SAMPLE;
    public static String[] getREG_SAMPLE()
    {
        REG_SAMPLE = new String[4];
        REG_SAMPLE[0]="CUS_NAME";
        REG_SAMPLE[1]="CUS_PHONE";
        REG_SAMPLE[2]="CUS_EMAIL";
        REG_SAMPLE[3]="CUS_ADDRESS";
        return REG_SAMPLE;          
    }   
}
```

This is the CreateDB table

```
public class CreateDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public CreateDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "restaurant";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String REGISTER="create table CUS_REGISTER(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "+
    ""+ "CUS_NAME text,"+"CUS_PHONE text,"+"CUS_EMAIL text,"+"CUS_ADDRESS text);";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        db.execSQL(REGISTER);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(CreateDB.class.getName(),"Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    }
}
```

This is the AdapterClass

```
public Cursor rawQuery(String args, String[] pColumnValues) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return database.rawQuery(DATABASE_TABLE, pColumnValues);

        }
```

Comment: @Niels :: there is not need do create an API just a query will do this first understand the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not able to fetch data from Sqlite Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268664/not-able-to-fetch-data-from-sqlite-database)

Comment: Thanks for giving response.