# Android Emulator Won't Start App on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

When I try to start an app to test it in the emulator, the emulator opens, then it installs the app (according to LogCat,) but it doesn't run. I looked in the applications, but it's not there. I have tried recreating the emulator, starting it from AVD Manager, resetting ADB, and more. This what LogCat gives me when I start the emulator:

```
[2012-05-13 20:25:23 - StickFigure] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Droid'
[2012-05-13 20:25:27 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
[2012-05-13 20:25:28 - Emulator] 
[2012-05-13 20:25:28 - StickFigure] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-05-13 20:25:28 - StickFigure] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-05-13 20:26:04 - StickFigure] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-05-13 20:26:04 - StickFigure] Uploading StickFigure.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-05-13 20:26:04 - StickFigure] Installing StickFigure.apk...
[2012-05-13 20:26:28 - StickFigure] Success!
[2012-05-13 20:26:28 - StickFigure] /StickFigure/bin/StickFigure.apk installed on device
[2012-05-13 20:26:28 - StickFigure] Done!
```

Edit: The emulator works fine with my other apps.

Comment: have you seen this answer?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793956/android-emulator-wont-run-application-started-from-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, verify that the **Launch Action** of your **Run configuration** is what you are expecting (Launch Default Activity or Launch a specific Activity).

If everything looks fine but the Activity is not being launched you can try doing it from the command line:

```
$ adb shell am start -n your.package/your.package.YourActivity
```