# Android Emulator not launching application

Tags: java, android, windows, eclipse, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Emulator won’t run application started from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793956/android-emulator-wont-run-application-started-from-eclipse)

I have a problem with Eclipse and Android. When I click the run button in Eclipse, it start the emulator, but not the app. If I hit the run button again while the emulator is still running, it just starts a new instance of the emulator, and once again, does not start the app.

This is all the Console output I get:

```
[2012-10-18 11:36:55 - FTS Live] Android Launch!
[2012-10-18 11:36:55 - FTS Live] adb is running normally.
[2012-10-18 11:36:55 - FTS Live] Performing com.robinj.fts.stream.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-10-18 11:36:55 - FTS Live] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Froyo' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2012-10-18 11:36:55 - FTS Live] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Froyo'
```

I have tried setting it so that it always tries to use the running AVD/device, but it just says there's none running, while there is.

--

Windows XP, Eclipse Juno, Android SDK, x86 (not that it's any better on Lubuntu 12.04 with Eclipse Indigo; There I can't even get an AVD to launch).

Comment: I had the same effect on my very first try. It worked later after restarting eclipse for the second time. Don't know what really happened there.

Comment: I had same problem. I close all the open emulators and launch one from AVD Manager. Then hit run.
Other option that also worked for me, change Run configurations in Eclipse for the app. Set it so that it always ask where to run the app and then choose the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

1> remove all instances of adb.exe from task manager.

2>run kill-server and then run start-server command.

3>restart eclipse.